# Clear download permission denial?

Tags: android, permissions, download

I want to clear download history by following code:

> getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://downloads/my_downloads"),
>   null, null);

But always failed because Permission Denial though I declared it!

> E/AndroidRuntime(3278): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
>   Denial: writing com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri
>   content://downloads/my_downloads from pid=3278, uid=10081 requires
>   android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
```

Just underneath the `<manifest>` tag

Comment: Thanks all the same.But I tried all corresponding permissions below, none work!    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER_ADVANCED" />

Comment: @thecr0w can you post your entire manifest file with the `uses-permission` tage present?