# How to get the downloaded file path using the download manager

Tags: android, file, path

I am able to download a video from the server using the download manager. However when I log the path using below code.

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(directory).getAbsolutePath() + subpath;
 Log.e("PATH", path);
```

I get

> 12-15 13:29:36.787 22807-22807/com.ezyagric.extension.android E/PATH: /storage/sdcard0/EZYAGRIC/Soil Testing.mp4.

Now this is different from the path on the phone which is

> /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ezyagric.extension.android/files/EZYAGRIC/Crop
>    Insurance.mp4

What brings that difference and how can obtain the path in the phone the way it is?

Comment: better to download on download folder...
`dmr.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);`

Comment: Do you mean the default folder as in   Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

Comment: yes @Rapheal download files there

Comment: Thanks @Singh let me try that

Comment: btw what are you passing in `directory` and `subpath`... if you want to download in default download folder i can give you code snippet

Comment: final String directory = "/EZYAGRIC";                                                                   
 final String subpath = "/"+videos.get(position).get("title").getAsString() + ".mp4";

Comment: Please send me the code snippet and I have a look

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code snippet to download file in default download directory.

```
DownloadManager.Request dmr = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

// If you know file name
String fileName = "filename.xyz"; 

//Alternative if you don't know filename
String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null,MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));

dmr.setTitle(fileName);
dmr.setDescription("Some descrition about file"); //optional
dmr.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
dmr.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
dmr.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(dmr);
```

**Note** For `mContext.getSystemService`

- Activity= `getSystemService();`
- Fragment= `getActivity.getSystemService();`
- Adapter=  `mContext.getSystemService(); //pass context in adapter`

**UPDATE**

As OP want to check file exist or not

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName); 
if(file.exists()){//File Exists};
```

Comment: Thanks let me try . And get back back to you

Comment: After downloading to the download folder , the path is /storage/sdcard0/Download/Soil Testing.mp4             .This is still different from the file path when I directly check on the phone which is /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ezyagric.extension.android/files/Download/Soil Testing.mp4..................First of all, are these paths supposed to be the same

Comment: file should be download at `/storage/sdcard0/Download/`

Comment: which is what I have      /storage/sdcard0/Download/Soil Testing.mp4

Comment: the path you are getting its for your app and the path you are setting for download is `DownloadManager` app path. first tell me where are your files downloading?

Comment: Ok I now see some light. Because what I was trying to achieve is to avoid downloading the video twice. So I wanted to first check the path in the local device to see if its already downloaded

Comment: The files are being downloaded in the downloads folder

Comment: you can check file exist of not by... `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), nameOfFile);    if(file.exists())`

Comment: Let me implement the checking bit. Otherwise thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Singh. Its finally working. After downloading, I check if it exists to avoid double download. It is now fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Raphael  instead of saying thanks try to express your feeling by upvote, downvote or by approving the answer. I not telling you because I want upvote but because it is an good habit to appreciate someone. Thanks

Comment: It is fine let me that

Comment: thanks for mentioning line below. it was really helpful. thank you
dmr.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

Answer (score 3):

You should try to download in download folder

```
        String url = "url you want to download";
        DownloadManager.Request request = new 
        DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDescription("Some descrition");
        request.setTitle("Some title");
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name-of-the-file.ext");

        // get download service and enqueue file
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Let me try I will get back to you. Otherwise thanks for the contribution

Comment: Welcome , Happy to Help

Comment: After downloading to the download folder , the path is /storage/sdcard0/Download/Soil Testing.mp4             .This is still different from the file path when I directly check on the phone which is /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ezyagric.extension.android/files/Download/Soil Testing.mp4..................First of all, are these paths supposed to be the same

Comment: try using setDestinationInExternalFilesDir instead of setDestinationInExternalPublicDir

Comment: let me do that now

Comment: Actually it is what am using

Comment: are you using any provider ?

Comment: No , I'm talking about file provider for supporting in Naugat

Comment: No but thanks for all your efforts, I have found the solution

Answer (score 2):

When you call --> **downloadManager.enqueue(request)** method before set their path

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"Google.gif");

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"google.gif"); // Set Your File Name
if (file.exists()) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    pro28_imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To download file without callback you can just enqueue it.

```
val fileUrl = "https://example.com/myfile.pdf"
val fileName = "myfile.pdf"
val fileExtension = File(fileName).extension
 val request = DownloadManager.Request(fileUrl.toUri()).apply {
            setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                fileName
            )
            setMimeType(
                MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                    .getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension)
            )
            allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION)
            setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        }

        val idDownloded = downloadManager?.enqueue(request) ?: return
```

But if you make the same downloads many times, then downloaded files will be stored as : "myfile-1.pdf", "myfile-2.pdf", "myfile-3.pdf"...

So, to get downloaded file path you need to do this:

```
val fileDownloadedUri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(idDownloded)//content://downloads/all_downloads/43
val mimeType = downloadManager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(idDownloded)

val fileDownloadedPath = FilesUtils.getPath(
            context = activity,
            uri = fileDownloadedUri
        )
```

where  FilesUtils (https://github.com/coltoscosmin/FileUtils/blob/master/FileUtils.java) from here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021624/2425851)

Then you may share the downloaded file:

```
val file = File(fileDownloadedPath)
        if (!file.exists()) {
            //error
            return
        }

        val uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
            file
        )

        val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            type = mimeType
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriForFile)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }

        activity.startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                intent,
                "Share"
            )
        )
```

How to configure FileProvider see this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579654/2425851)