# Android android.os.FileUriExposedException Error in Android N

Tags: android

I have images in external storage in Orders folder and that image i am trying to share to external apps using  intent

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Orders");
String filename = "OrderID.jpg";
File file = new File(file,filename);
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
                try {
                     startActivity(intent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

                }
```

I have given storage permission on loading application itself but i get every time app crashes

```
ndroid.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Orders/OrderID.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

Can any one help me how i cant fix this ?
i have followed many post in google but no use

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251634/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-jpg-exposed-beyond-app-through-clipdata)

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/185

https://github.com/tungdx/android-media-picker/issues/11

https://github.com/MLSDev/RxImagePicker/issues/13

Comment: check the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use **FileProvider** when you want to share files to other apps.

check https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.

use **FileProvider.getUriForFile** to get Uri instead of `Uri.fromFile(file)` in you code.

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"your_package.fileprovider",photoFile);
```

Comment: @Man.i have already  <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

Comment: i acepted answer for the clue FileProvider when you want to share files to other apps.