# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/967

Tags: android, exception

The cursor returns null while using the Uri.

code is here:
https://notepad.pw/c1uhwjzr

Comment: here is my code: `if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                    try {
                        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        return split[1];
                    }
                }`

Comment: Some lines deleted for space issue .here is Cursor part: `("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
               
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                }`

Comment: Edit your question instead writing code in comments.

Comment: don't put code in comments, edit the question instead

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671548/unknown-url-content-downloads-my-downloads/53021624